# Exporting very large matrices using JMatio in Java

Tags: java, matlab, sparse-matrix

I need to export very large 3d matrices to Matlab from Java. I have written a class for creating a 3d matrix which works very well for small matrices but breaks down for large ones. The codes is as follows:

```
public class MLDouble3d extends MLDouble {
    private final int i;
    private final int j;
    public MLDouble3d(String name, int[] dims) {
        super(name, dims);
        i=dims[0];
        j=dims[1];
    }

    public void set(double value, int ii, int jj, int kk){
        set(value, ii + jj * i + kk * i * j);
    }
}
```

I get the following error when I run with a large matrix:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.nio.Buffer.position(Buffer.java:236)
    at com.jmatio.types.MLNumericArray._set(MLNumericArray.java:269)
    at com.jmatio.types.MLNumericArray.setReal(MLNumericArray.java:111)
    at com.jmatio.types.MLNumericArray.set(MLNumericArray.java:215)
```

I've tried using MLSparse, however it cannot be used to create 3d matrices in this way.

I run the virtual machine with the following options:

```
-Xms24000M -Xmx24000M -Xmn16000M -XX:TLABSize=1m -XX:-ResizeTLAB
```

I am able to fit the data in a double[][][] array.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that dims[0]*dims[1]*dims[2] is to large for integers, it can't be larger than 2,147,483,647. Otherwise an integer can't store the index.

Comment: Is there any way around it? Like changing integer to long, for example? Or maybe a different library?

Comment: I would store the java `double[][][]` in a file using any java library (e.g. hibernate, xml, whatever) and load it within matlab via java. Java-Code can be executed directly from matlab command line.

Comment: The integer constraint comes from the MAT5 format itself. A mat file can be arbitrarily large, but each root-level variable is limited to 2GB. One thing you could do is to split the matrices into separate root-level variables, e.g., one for each column (or maybe a set of 10 columns - whatever fits the 2GB limit), and then combine them in MATLAB later using `matFile()` and iterating over the fields. (hint: you can access fields by strings, e.g., `myData.(['col' num2str(i)])`)